# how to rectify "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 " error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Guys i'm trying to actually create a feed like facebook's feed here but i get this error that i cant figure out where im going wrong.
here is the code:

```
$sql3="select u.update_id, u.update_body,u.account_name,u.os_id,u.author,u.time,u.title,"
            . "c.comment_body, c.os_id,c.author,c.time"
            . "from updates as u, comment_update as c "
            . "where c.os_id=u.update_id and u.account_name = ':session' and u.type in ('a','c') and u.account_name=':friend' and u.type =('a'|'c') order by u.time asc,c.time desc";
     $stmth=$conn->prepare($sql3);
   $stmth->execute(array(":session"=>$_SESSION['uname'],":friend"=>$friend));
    $status_reply= $stmth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

here is the error code:-

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as u, comment_update as c where c.os_id=u.update_id and u.account_name = ':sessi' at line 1' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project-chg/status&comments.php:28 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/project-chg/status&comments.php(28): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/project-chg/example1.php(30): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project-chg/status&comments.php on line 28

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to add a space before "from" in your query.

Comment: @Thevenin thanks bro that solved the error but now a new error comes  like this `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project-chg/status&comments.php:28 `

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$sql3="select u.update_id, u.update_body,u.account_name,u.os_id,u.author,u.time,u.title,"
            . "c.comment_body, c.os_id,c.author,c.time"
            . "from updates as u, comment_update as c "
            . "where c.os_id=u.update_id and u.account_name = ':session' and u.type in ('a','c') and u.account_name=':friend' and u.type =('a'|'c') order by u.time asc,c.time desc";
```

1. Add space before from
2. Change `('a'|'c')`  to `('a','c')`
3. Consider using `JOIN` syntax instad of comma syntax
4. Probably you need to remove `'` around `:friend` and `:session`
5. Whole `WHERE clause conditions` are very odd for me `u.account_name = :session and u.account_name=:friend` the same column??? + doubled `u.type` condition

Result:

```
$sql3="select u.update_id, u.update_body,u.account_name,u.os_id,u.author,u.time,u.title,"
            . "c.comment_body, c.os_id,c.author,c.time"
            . " from updates as u JOIN comment_update as c ON c.os_id=u.update_id "
            . "where u.account_name = :session and u.type in ('a','c') and u.account_name=:friend and u.type =('a','c') order by u.time asc,c.time desc";
```